# submit event should be emitted when submitting form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue login in component that fails a test:

```
LoginForm should emit submit event

Error:
  submit event should be emitted when submitting form

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Button:

```
  <button type="button" id="login-button" :disabled="!enableSubmit" @click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Methods:

```
 submit() {
    if(this.username != "" && this.password != "") {
      this.$emit("You have successfully loged in", this.username && this.password)
    } else {
      console.log("Not logged in")
    }
  }
```

How do I correctly emit the submit event?

Answer (score 1):

```
submit() {
  if(this.username != "" && this.password != "") {
    this.$emit("submit", this.username && this.password)
  } else {
    console.log("Not logged in")
  }
}
```

In your parent component, you can listen for the submit event emitted by your child component like this:

```
<LoginForm @submit="handleSubmit" />


methods: {
  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that if it was in one component?